# C++ Converting string[4] to a string

Tags: c++

I want to change the last character of a word to be a string.

thanks!

EDIT: adding Jon's attempted answer as it provides some insight into what his functional requirement is:

```
string x = "apple"; char c = apple[4]; string q = "";
string z = q+c;
```

Comment: Ummm... what? Can you post some code to show what you've got so far, and give us an example of what you wish to accomplish?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: word as in a a c-string? string class has overloaded = operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string x = "apple";
std::string z(x.substr(4, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
string x = "apple";
char c = apple[4];
string q = "";

string z = q+c;
```

Comment: Try selecting your code, and then click on the 101 010 button.

Comment: This would: `string x = "apple"; string z( 1, x[ 4 ] );`

Answer (score 0):

If you got a char[] lets say char arr[] = "Lalelu THis is a for-worded word:P";

Then you could try:

```
std::string str; str.assign(&arr[strlen(arr)-5], 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
std::string apple = "apple";
std::string fpp(apple.rbegin(), apple.rbegin() + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string MyString = "Whee!"; // String to extract letter from.

char LastChar = MyString.at(MyString.length() - 1); // Retrieves the last letter of the string and stores it as a char.
string LastCharAsString = string(1, LastChar); // Typecasts the char to a string.
```

Untested, as I don't have access to a compiler ATM.

Comment: there is no constructor that takes a `char` alone, you have to provide a size as well, i.e. `string(1, LastChar);`